# Empty white space between the 2 images

Tags: css

I have placed 2 images side by side in a div besides input box "Search by Contact". In the browser I find there is a gap between the 2nd image(Button T) and the one on its left. I am unable to remove the gap. Any help is highly appreciated. Here is the link to the html page:
[Space between button T and the one on its left.](http://shivanand.in/forums/popup/oc_popup.html)

Comment: This must be the question of the month, because I've seen it come up on several times between SO and some web design blogs I follow.

Comment: Gosh, so many dupes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931913/how-can-i-stop-the-new-line-from-adding-a-space-between-my-list-items-in-html, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276324/css-horizontal-navigation-spacing, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441279/firefox-3-adds-spacing-to-spans-with-displayinline-block...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is white space between the images in the HTML code and since images are in-line elements (similar to text), there will be white space on the rendered page.

Comment: There is a line break and a line break is white space.

Comment: To add to the explanation: white space is collapsed into a single space by default - for all content except content inside a `pre` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Trying setting the style on your links to have `margin-right:0px`, e.g.

```
<a href="#" style="margin-right: 0px"><img ... ></a>
```

(It would of course be preferable to do this using a CSS class...)